# Prove: $ \vdash (P \land Q) \leftrightarrow (Q \land P)$

Tags: logic, proof-verification

Prove: $ \vdash (P \land Q) \leftrightarrow (Q \land P)$.

Exactly that.  I cannot figure this out for the life of me.  All I have is:

1. │$P \land Q$
2. │   │$Q \land P$

I can already assume that there is more than 10 steps at least, but have no idea where I am going with this proof.

Any help as to the next step would be more than appreciated.

Comment: Steps 1-5 as shown.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are talking about *natural deduction*. The derivation is simple as this:

> > 1) $P \land Q$, Hypothesis
> >
> > 2) $Q$, 1 $\land$-Elim 2
> >
> > 3) $P$, 1 $\land$-Elim 1
> >
> > 4) $Q \land P$, 2, 3 $\land$-Intro
>
> 5) $(P \land Q) \to (Q \land P)$, 1-4 $\to$-Intro

This only shows ($\implies$) though. Can you now complete the proof?

Comment: Bruno, Indeed a natural deduction.  I see, I jumped strait to step 4 without validifying it.  Yeah, next id have to validify the other set; (Q^P)-->(P^Q) with similar steps, correct?  Then set them in the end <--> to each other?  I apologize for not elaborating more, I am in class right now.  I'll get on later and illustrate the steps I concluded.

Comment: Steps 1-5 as shown through Bruno.

6. │Q ^ P, Hypothesis
7. │P, 1 ^ -Elim 1
8. │Q, 1 ^ -Elim 2
9. │P ^ Q, 7, 8 ^ -Intro
10. (Q ^ P) --> (P ^ Q), 6-9 --> -Intro
11. (P ^ Q) <--> (Q ^ P), Conclusion. 

Would this be how the proof would then follow?

Comment: @AllenAllen Yes, but be careful with some essential details: in (7) and (8) you must apply $\land$-elim in (6), not in (1) - besides, (1) does not exist anymore: as a hypothesis, we say it were *discharged* by $\to$-intro in (5). Also, remember [always] justifying all lines, e.g. (11), when working on natural deduction, our chain of reasoning must always be explicit/transparent.